# не работает vagrant up

Tags: virtualbox, vagrant

Приветствую, очень нужна помощь! Установила VirtualBox-5.2.8-121009 и Vagrant 2.0.2_i686. После набора команды vagrant up выдаёт ошибку:

```
С:\Users\User\OpenServer\domains\invest>vagrant up
Bringing machine 'invest' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> invest: Resuming suspended VM...
==> invest: Booting VM...
==> invest: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
invest: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
invest: SSH username: vagrant
invest: SSH auth method: private key
invest:
invest: Vagrant insecure key detected. Vagrant will automatically replace
invest: this with a newly generated keypair for better security.
invest:
invest: Inserting generated public key within guest...
The guest machine entered an invalid state while waiting for it
to boot. Valid states are 'restoring, running'. The machine is in the
'paused' state. Please verify everything is configured
properly and try again.

If the provider you're using has a GUI that comes with it,
it is often helpful to open that and watch the machine, since the
GUI often has more helpful error messages than Vagrant can retrieve.
For example, if you're using VirtualBox, run `vagrant up` while the
VirtualBox GUI is open.

The primary issue for this error is that the provider you're using
is not properly configured. This is very rarely a Vagrant issue.
```

3 дня мучаюсь с этими ошибками, весь интернет перевернула, устанавливала и прошлые версии VirtualBox но безрезультатно..

Comment: Я конечно это сделаю, но естественно ошибку не полностью изложу так как столько писать нереально..поэтому решила скриншотами показать

Comment: запустите virtualbox GUI перед запуском `vagrant up`, чтобы посмотреть  есть ли ещё сообщения об ошибке¶ И/или зайдите вручную в VM и перегенерите ssh ключи

Comment: Спасибо Вам большое, но я с ошибками целую неделю мучалась, то одна, то другая.. я уже устала с ними, и просто начала работу на OpenServer*))